# Java JAR application: how does the structure look like? (Eclipse)

Tags: java

I'm a seasoned PHP programmer with backgrounds within Powershell, JavaScript etc.
I see the benefits with Java and wish to dig deeper.

All the documentation though is too advanced for me atm.

A typical PHP structure:

```
index.php
classes/class_get.php
classes/class_set.php
```

Where in index.php you would have the lines

```
require_once "classes/class_get.php";
require_once "classes/class_set.php";
```

Now in Java...
I understand Windows files are in .JAR format. No problem here, easy to understand.
I am confused when creating this in eclipse. Is the strucutre;

```
Main.java
src*/defaultPackage**/myClass.java
```

* folder
** package

Where in the Main.java file you would declare "import myClass.java"?

Also other packages such as the following:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.swing.*;
```

I am getting errors, and this manifest file, I haven't heard of it in any tutorials yet?

Comment: What is take exception? stack trace needed

Comment: http://eclipsetutorial.sourceforge.net/totalbeginner.html

Comment: Whoa! lots of questions. ^_^ You are trying to use Swing? Do you have the proper JAR reference on your build path?

Comment: this site explains it abit better: http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/85application/jar/jar.html

anyone explain more?

Comment: gigadot, was there, just made me more confused!

Comment: what do you mean build path and JAR reference? (this is exactly what I'm meaning, I don't understand whats required for files to work!)

Comment: i don't think you should try to understand manifest files or folder structure at the moment. you should try to understand how to use your ide first. it will generate manifest and everything for you. once you are good enough you may want to learn the low level configuration which you may never need to.

Comment: Unlike PHP (scripting language), Java is a compiled language so the code file (\*.java) needs to be compiled into machine code (\*.class) (it's not really machine code as for c, c++, etc.). The temporary folder for storing the compiled files is called "build path". I'm not sure what JAR reference is, maybe it's a path to libraries.

Comment: Thank you Gigadot, your making more sense than +10 pages I've read!

Comment: You are welcome. Remember don't jump to far in one step when you learn Java.

Comment: I'm a fast learner and learn best by example! Was wondering could you explain this whole thing with the manifest file?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, this is the way to create a jar or runnable jar in eclipse

File -> Export-> Java ->Runnbale JAR file

Launch configuration : your Class containing the public static void main(String[] args)

Export destination : Target place

Library Handling:

Package required libraries into generated JAR

FINISH

Comment: Exactly what I've done! However when I run the .JAR file I receive the error "Could not find the main class: defaultPackage.myClass. Program will exit.".
People say this has to do with the manifest file however I have no idea, what that is, where it is, or how I fix it!

Comment: i hope your file which contains your class that has the main inside it, got the same name...thats important in eclipse. If possible can you pls put all the class file names in the project and also mark the class which has the main method in it.

Comment: Yes it has the main void function inside it. I found what the error was , I was running an executable JAR file ad not a Jar File. However how do I export to a executable JAR and make it work?

Comment: Same as you did with JAR File, select the executable JAR as i mentioned in my post, i have tried it out with a swing program and it worked fine. Once created double click on the executable JAR File, and its works... i am not sure abt the command line programs present in the executable JARS

Answer (score 1):

- a) There are no Windows files in Java. Java is cross platform.
- b) Something with a slash delimiter is always a folder. Something with a dot is always a package. Don't confuse them, because it is confusing enough.
- c) Don't use the term "defaulPackage", because there is such a term for the case, that you don't specify any package. Then the package of your class is called the default package.

> Main.java
> src*/defaultPackage**/myClass.java
>
> Where in the Main.java file you would declare "import  myClass.java"?

You never import something .java, because you import a class, not a source file. Often you only have third party compiled classes in a jar, and don't have the source. Well - maybe.

If your class belongs to a package, the name of the class is the whole package name. You can omit it from classes in the same package.

So we don't know whether Main and MyClass (use Upper case, if you like to communicate with others - else you're confusing us) belong to the same package.

If so: Don't import anything.

Else: Import the whole package name, which might contain multiple dots.

So for example:

```
 import yourCompany.games.monstersahead.*;
```

or

```
 import yourCompany.games.monstersahead.MyClass;
```

for example.

The package name will usually not contain folder names like src, bin, classes.

Comment: Thank you, I now understand what packages are. They contain compiled .java files which are called .class files.
I understand the wildcard importing now. Excellent!

I am receiving however double messages about this "manifest" file. Some say it is automatically made when you export to a executable .JAR file and others say you have to insert what packages you use into this file via cmd prompt. Why not have this all done in Eclipse? (I am receiving this "cannot find the main-class..." error)

Comment: @KarlMorrison: Well, it depends on Eclise/jar version. Former (1.5?) versions of jar didn't make manifest files with a main class. And there are good reasons (for example testing, or multi purpose jar) to have multiple classes with a main class in a single jar. I'm not 100% happy with your statement about packages. Packages contain classes, not class files. Folders and Jars contain files, but files aren't classes. Packages contain classes, interfaces. A file can contain multiple classes, nested classes, and you can develop two classes which are in the same package in different directories. ...

Comment: If you understand how a Manifest has to look like, how to produce it with the jar tool, it is easy to set up eclipse, netbeans, ant, maven, intellij, ... . If you learn how to use a tool, you often have problems to configure another one, where it is in a different menu.

Comment: Ok! Got Java 1.7 (7), so there is no way for Eclipse to create this manifest file? Sounds abit awkward?

Comment: From what I have read in other postings about Jars, it is more easy than before, but since my version of eclipse is a bit outdated, I can't explain the more modern ways to do it today.